# List of Objects In Change Notifier don't update

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I have a list of objects that inherit from ChangeNotifier. I have removed the types just to simplify stuff.

```
class TaskListsState with ChangeNotifier {
  List _lists = List();
  _currentList;

  List get lists => _lists;
  get currentList => _currentList;

  set lists(List newValue) {
    this._lists = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set currentList(newValue) {
    this._currentList = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  TaskListsState() {
    this._lists = [
      ToDoListState(),
      ToCreateListState(),
      ToDecideListState(),
      BalancedMeListState()
    ];

    this._currentList = this._lists[0];
  }
}
```

All of the objects inherit from a base class but generally, this is how they look

```
class ToCreateListState with ChangeNotifier implements TaskListState {
  String title = "TO CREATE LIST";
  String alias = "tocreate";
  bool _loading = false;
  List<TaskState> _tasks;

  bool get loading => _loading;
  List<TaskState> get tasks => _tasks;

  set tasks(List<TaskState> newValue) {
    this._tasks = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set loading(bool newValue) {
    _loading = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  ToCreateListState();

  removeTask(TaskState task) {
    this._tasks.remove(task);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Now, when I update one of the list objects, they don't update in the UI. How can I fix this, please?

Currently, this is how I am using it in the view:

```
 MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => TaskListsState(),
        ),

      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: '',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        initialRoute: defaultHome,
        onGenerateRoute: onGenerateRoute,
      ),
    );
```

Then when I want to use one of the items in my screen I would do `Provider.of<TaskListsState>(context).lists[index].whateverValue =. anotherValue;`

However, it doesn't update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the `Provider.of<TaskListsState>(context).lists[index].whateverValue =. anotherValue;` it won't call `notifyListeners()` because it doesn't update the `lists` itself.

You can simply create a method inside the `TaskListsState` that does the modification for you and afterwards calls the `notifyListeners()`

```dart
class TaskListsState with ChangeNotifier {
...
    void updateWhateverValue(int index, dynamic value) {
        lists[index].whateverValue = value;
        notifyListeners();
    }
...
}
```

You should replace the `dynamic` with the object you have.

Comment: Ok, I will try this now

Comment: But what if I have deeply nested objects, this wouldn't be ideal....What would I do then?

Comment: Or better still, if I have multiple methods to implement (my case). What would I do then?

Comment: You can make those objects also `ChangeNotifier` and provide them where they are needed, probably in a list of some sorts. The flutter team had an awsome talk explaining this: https://youtu.be/d_m5csmrf7I?t=1456

Comment: I will check it out now. Thanks

Comment: hello i tried this but my Consumer returns Emprty lists every time. help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67282912/unable-to-create-getter-in-changenotifier-class-error-when-using-provider-in-fl    i posted my question here please check.

Comment: can you please share your code step for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another explanation:
Imagine we have this class

```
class Products with ChangeNotifier
{

List<String> prods =new List() :

List<String> getProds => prods;

Void addprod() 
{
prods.add('chocolate');
prods.add('beer');
notifyListeners();
} 

Products()
{
addprod();
}


}
```

So we have a class products which has already two products.

Case of removing a product, if we call

`Provider.of<Products>(context)().products.remove('beer')`

Beer will get removed but all other Consumers will not get Notified, since remove is a predefined function and doesn't exist on Products class as a Notifier.

Make sure everytime you are calling a function, it's Actually updating something in your data model class, so you can notice changes.

Hope that clarify your vision.

Comment: This doesn't work for nested objects. Thanks for trying though but the youtube video provided in the first answer worked for me